# The first view in the Jamie Oliver Recipe App

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

Is the first view in the Jamie Oliver recipe app a tableview? If so, then how can this effect be achieved and if not, then is it just buttons that have beeen added to a scrollview and set with a push action?

[image]

Comment: attach a screenshot please

Comment: upload a screenshot to http://imgur.com since you wont be able to add an image to this post

Comment: “How do they do that” type of questions are off topic. Try to replicate the behavior and post any specific doubt you encounter. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142857/ PS: you can use a scrollview or a table, looks like the later to me.

Comment: Here is a [tutorial](http://skeuo.com/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial) that I think might help you.

Comment: Thanks to all and thanks for uploading the picture. I just got back to my computer. I couldn't add the picture which I tried in the beginning but I just made an account today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could certainly do that with a table view.  Set a custom background image for the entire table view.  Make each table view cell transparent and give it some image views (for the food picture, the picture border, and the clip) and labels (for “Ultimate Curry Night” and “10 Recipes”).  Possibly the labels have custom background images.

I don't think anything on that screen would be hard to program.  You just need to get good-looking artwork.

Comment: Thank you for your great response. You are definately right about that. The artwork makes the app look amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Yupp `UITableView` is the medicine here. In fact I would actively advise against using `UIScrollView` as every view in `UIScrollView` loads in one single shot thereby giving a crappy user experience. Whereas `UItableView` nicely loads only the first few visible cells and on demand loads the rest based on user action.

Then they have just used custom `UITableViewCell` with `UImageView` and other `UILabels`, pretty easy actually. The tough part is to get Jamie Oliver to give you such great looking food...